# Does the Riemann tensor encode all information about the second derivatives of the metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, curvature, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

In answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203677/why-is-the-riemann-curvature-tensor-the-technical-expression-of-curvature) I suggested the following as a motivation for the definition of the Riemann tensor:

> Let $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ be two dim-$n$ Lorentzian
>   manifolds with points $x\in\mathcal M$ and $y\in\mathcal N$. Then you
>   can pick local coordinates on $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ such that
>   the expressions for $g_{\mu\nu}$ agree to second order near $x$ and
>   $y$ iff you can find bases at $x$ and $y$ such that the Riemann
>   tensors are equal.

Is the preceding theorem in fact true? Where can I find a proof of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2002/vol3-n2/Wolfe/Rmn_Metric.pdf) is a reference for Riemannian manifolds. The theorem (4.1) is that the Taylor expansion of a Riemannian metric $g$ in coordinates has the form
$$ g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}R_{ikjl}x^kx^l - \frac{1}{6}\nabla_m R_{ikjl}x^kx^lx^m + O(x^4). $$

This is surely also true in the pseudo-Riemannian setting. O'Neill's book probably has this stated and proved somewhere in the first several chapters. I don't have it handy at the moment but will verify when I get home.

Comment: May be this? Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity, 103 Barrett O'Neill ,Academic Press, 29-Jul-1983